# What is a GenericTypeResolver and how it works?

Tags: java, spring

I am working to create .NET porting of an open source Java project.

Since I am not a java expert, some times I encounter some code that I can't understand:

```
 private UserAgentAnnotationMapper<T> mapper = null;
 public void initialize(UserAgentAnnotationMapper<T> theMapper) {
        mapper = theMapper;

        Class[] classOfTArray = GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments(mapper.getClass(), UserAgentAnnotationMapper.class);
```

As I read on spring documentation:

> 

```
public abstract class GenericTypeResolver extends java.lang.Object
```

> Helper class for resolving generic types against type variables.
>
> Mainly intended for usage within the framework, resolving method
>   parameter types even when they are declared generically

But I can't understand: UserAgentAnnotationMapper is a generic interface, in what sense resolves generic typed against type variables?

As I see the code returns an array of classes that I don't understand how they are correlated to the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method resolves how the typevariable `T` is specified in the type of variable `mapper`.

E.g. if `mapper` is of type

```
class IntegerMapper implements UserAgentAnnotationMapper<Integer> {
 // ..
}
```

it will return with an array containing `Integer.class`

Comment: Do you know, why returns an array?
Based on your example can always return only a single value.

Comment: You can have more than one generic parameter, eg. `Map<String,String>`